# water tap leaking, loosen the nut

Tags: water, leak, taps

A water tap located in the basement is leaking when tap is opened. I inspected the tap, hoping that tightening nut would help, but it seems that the nut is sort of "soldered", i.e. it won't move:

[image]

Then I unscrewed the blue handle, and found a small plastic cap under it, that covers a shaft. I thought I'd be able to get in, if take out the shaft, and change gasket. However it seems that there's no way to loosen shaft either.

[image]

Is there a way to resolve this or I'll have to replace the whole tap?

Comment: Some times the nut can be a real bugger to get off. You should use 2 wrenches 1 to support the valve body and 1 on the nut. I keep Gortex rope or string in my repair kit, when leaks like this pop up several wraps on the shaft under the nut and reassembly will fix it if the correct rubber cannot be found. Make sure to turn the water off at the main or meter or you will have a new indoor shower until the water is turned off.

Comment: @Ed, thanks for advice, will try. Is there a way to figure the threading, left or right, of the nut before applying force to loosen it?